# discord.js command on avatar

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a problem with the avatar display command. It keep saying this:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined

Code:

```js
const { Client, Message, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {

    name: 'avatar',
    execute: async(client, message, args) => {
        const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member;

        message.channel.send(
            new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${member.user.tag}'s avatar`)
            .setImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 512}))
            .setColor('RED')
        );
    },
};
```

Comment: Have you confirmed `message` is a valid Message object? Try logging it

Comment: Maybe your parameters are in the wrong order

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation here is that you passed your parameters in the wrong order. Your declaration is like this:

```
(client, message, args)
```

however your execution parameters are passed in incorrectly. I suspect they might look something like this:

```
(message, client, args)
```

but they *must* be in the right order

```
(client, message, args)
```